# Why don't we use the letter "s" to form a genitive in this example?

Tags: possessives, proper-nouns, attributive-nouns

Why do we say

> **Pauli** exclusion principle

instead of

> **Pauli's** exclusion principle

When we want to say that something belongs to somebody, we should use the "s" to form a genitive, i.e.  "this is Pauli's cat", not "this is Pauli cat".

Comment: Possible duplicate of *["the Poincare conjecture" but "Bolzano's theorem"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24690/the-poincare-conjecture-but-bolzanos-theorem)*. Also see at EL&U *[Why do we write “Fourier's law” but “Soret effect”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/199401)* and *[“somebody's theme” vs “somebody theme” — Saxon genitive dilemma](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142126)*.

Comment: @Sam Harrington, I rephrased the question from in title. But both questions mean the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question! This is the transition from possession of an idea or object to having that idea or object be named after that person. The best example I can think of has to do with violins.

One of my favorite violinists, Joshua Bell, plays on a very old and expensive Stradivarius violin. This violin is now known as the [Gibson Ex-Huberman violin (and has a cool story behind it).](http://www.joshuabell.com/story-his-violin)

This is because this violin used to be own by another famous violinist, George Alfred Gibson. When Gibson had the instrument, people would probably refer to the instrument at Gibson's violin. At that time, it was his instrument - his possession. But as he was such a prominent violinist, when he died and the violin was sold to someone else, the violin was named after him, and still bears his name today - the "Gibson Stradivarius." The "ex-Huberman" part you can read about on your own.

In short, the principle in your question has been named AFTER Pauli. It is not his principle, but it is named after him.

Same thing goes for many buildings. Carnegie Hall in New York City was funded by Andrew Carnegie, and so was named after him. It is not Carnegie's Hall.

However, I will note that you will see occasionally an "s" thrown in with principles, especially ones that are newer. For example,

> [Einstein's Theory of Relativity](http://www.space.com/17661-theory-general-relativity.html)

In this case, it is HIS theory. The theory isn't named after him. However, we often refer to the theory as Einstein's Theory of Relativity, so it has, in effect, become the name of the theory. These things occasionally get mixed.

(You can read about all of the [Stradivarius instruments that are left today on Wikipedia here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Stradivarius_instruments), in case you're interested).

Comment: To be clear, Alex K is talking about possession, not authorship.  Wolfgang Pauli absolutely did discover the exclusion principle, but he does not own it.

Comment: @JasonPatterson good point. Fixed!